# custom UIVIew with nib subviews nil

Tags: objective-c, uiview

I create a simple custom UIView with a xib file, I connect xib view to my class, then I linked my IBOutles to subviews, after this I create the view with initWithFrame and I add it programmatically to my parent view

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        NSArray *objects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AddAlarmView" owner:self options:nil];
        _scrollView = (UIScrollView *)[objects objectAtIndex:0];
        [self addSubview:_scrollView];

    }
    return self;
}
```

the problem is that all the subviews are nil....if I try to get customView.textFeild1 it is nil....why?where is the mistake?

Comment: Is your ScrollView object is in xib or the UIView is in the xib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this you should try to get your UIView object from Xib like this..

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    NSArray *objects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AddAlarmView" owner:self options:nil];
    self = (YourClassName *)[objects objectAtIndex:0];
    self.frame = frame;
    return self;
}
```

You don't need to add subViews again your IBOutLets. They are already subView of your View in xib file.
Simply load that xib file and assign it to your self and update your frame according to the parameter.

Comment: I solved in this way:
        self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AddAlarmView"
                                              owner:self
                                            options:nil] lastObject];